# Panels, Diff and nodes

Tags: 7, panels

Does the Diff module work with nodes that are displayed using the Panels template? I go to `/revisions` and I get a "Page not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A panels display for a node should not affect diff/revisions.

Is there a revision tab for the node?  "node/NID/revisions" also were any revisions created for the node for diff to even compare? By default they won't create a revision.